# Is there a better way to change an Image in an ImageView by clicking a button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview, uiimage

Currently I am changing an image view by doing the following:

```
@IBOutlet var bgImage: UIImageView!
```

creating a UIimage view connected in storyboard
and

```
var counter = 0
    @IBAction func ChangePic(){

        //print(counter)
        if(counter == 15){
              counter = 0
        }

        let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: String(counter))!
        bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
        bgImage.image = UIImage(named: String(counter))
        self.view.addSubview(bgImage!)
        counter = counter + 1

    }
```

Modifying the imageview  here,this function is connected to a button in storyboard so that when you click it it changes the picture. the reason there is a counter is because the photos are enumerated from one 0-14 so I can easily display them. This works well enough but the images resize themselves and keep appearing on top of each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the image you just have to do this:

```
@IBAction func ChangePic(){

        //print(counter)
        if(counter == 15){
              counter = 0
        }

        bgImage.image = UIImage(named: String(counter))
        counter = counter + 1

    }
```

Your current code:

```
@IBAction func ChangePic(){

        //print(counter)
        if(counter == 15){
              counter = 0
        }

        // You create new image
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: String(counter))!

        // You set new instance to your imageView with your updated image (No need to do this because the object is not nil)
        bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)

        // You set again your updated image (only this line required )
        bgImage.image = UIImage(named: String(counter))

        // No needed
        self.view.addSubview(bgImage!)


        counter = counter + 1

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the imageView bgImage, all you have to do is set the image property on bgImage. You don't need to create a new imageView every time.

```
@IBAction func ChangePic(){

   if(counter == 15){
          counter = 0
    }
    bgImage.image = UIImage(named: String(counter))
    counter = counter + 1
}
```